# Most efficient way to create an NSMutableArray from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Which of these, if either, is more efficient?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@1, @2]];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *array = [@[@1, @2] mutableCopy];
```

Or are these the same internally?

Comment: Are they the same internally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two options you provide both first create an `NSArray` and then create an `NSMutableArray` from the `NSArray` so there is essentially no difference.

There is a third option that would be ever so slightly better in this case:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@1, @2, nil];
```

This doesn't create an intermediate `NSArray` like your other two options.

Answer (score 0):

While using ARC there is no difference in your example. But if you would use NSArray variable instead of static @[@1, @2], in case of this array being nil the first would return you empty array and the second one will return you nil.